# Why does time measurement sometimes return repetitive values (multiples of 15.625ms)?

Tags: c++, time

I've done a lot of searching and found similar questions, but I still can't understand why **sometimes** my code gets the time right, and other times decides to become useless and return repetitive values.

A simple C++ code you can run to test this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <windows.h>
//#include <unistd.h>  //For Unix

void stall(int milisseconds){
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    Sleep(milisseconds);
    //usleep(milisseconds*1000);   //For Unix

    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(finish-start).count()/1000000.0<<" ms\n";
}

int main(){
    std::cout<<"Begin\n";
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++){
        stall(i);
    }
}
```

Running this, the expected output would be something like:

```
1 ms
2 ms
3 ms
4 ms
...
98 ms
99 ms
100 ms
```

Sometimes it works, but other times (like, at random), the output looks like this:

```
15.625 ms
15.62 ms
15.632 ms
7.997 ms
16.713 ms
15.637 ms
31.25 ms
31.263 ms
31.245 ms
31.25 ms
21.985 ms
...
93.718 ms
93.77 ms
93.744 ms
102.263 ms
109.369 ms
96.192 ms
109.367 ms
109.368 ms
```

How can I eliminate this awful inconsistency? Reducing the number of background processes doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Unrelated: std::this_thead::sleep_for (and sleep_until) my solve your non-cross platform code

Comment: I get your expected values. Do you run this as one thread? or is it a part of some bigger process?

Comment: did you try `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(milisseconds));` ?

Comment: Fixing my comment about converting to milliseconds directly, you can do this and keep the decimals by converting to `duration<double, milli>` (works well with a type alias). That saves you the worry of messing up the math and the same for code reviewers.

Comment: It's a single thread. And this loop with a sleep command is just a tiny example so my problem can be easily replicated and understood. I'm actually facing it with a bigger program that measures the running time of reasonably large functions that take variable time (making it even less desirable to return these repetitive times)

Comment: Sleep() yields the processor and the thread is only eligible for execution again when the clock tick interrupt causes the thread scheduler to be re-activated.  The normal state of the processor is to be turned off completely while the machine is idle, stopped on a HLT instruction.  Only an interrupt can wake it up again.  15.625 is the normal rate but programs do mess with this rate, browsers in particular.  Chrome is particularly notorious, cranks it all the way down to 1 msec.  Bad for power consumption.  How you got multiples of 15.625 is hard to see from the snippet, code is missing.

Comment: If you need 1 msec resolution then you can get it by calling timeBeginPeriod().

Answer (score 1):

I would guess this would be due to your OS' scheduling quantum: If your thread yields or finishes its execution time quantum, some other threads will run for that quantum, and then when your thread runs again, a full quantum (and a bit) has elapsed. So you see advances by noise + either 0 quanta or 1 quantum.

Comment: Your answer makes me understand that it's really something beyond my control. But how could a stopwatch application work in this condition then? I would expect that any application that it's supposed to measure time by fractions of a second (like a racing game) would be able to output any value between 0 and 999 ms, instead of being limited to just "15ms, 31ms, 46ms, 62ms, etc" due to the OS' scheduling quantum.

Comment: @DanielFranklin: A typical OS is not intended to allow such exact timing of execution. For that, you need either a [real-time OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system), a real-time-adaptation of a regular OS, or an addition to the OS kernel which allows you more leeway w.r.t. scheduling.

Comment: OK, I SOMEHOW FOUND A WAY OF MANIPULATING THE PROCESS SCHEDULING ALGORITHM IN MY FAVOR. Check out my answer I gave to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

einpoklum suggested that it could be because of my OS' scheduling quantum, which sounds about right. I was about to go crazy, thinking that it was something beyond my control (or too complicated to solve), but I ended up somehow discovering a way of manipulating it in my favor. I noticed that, if the internet browser was closed, the times returned were a very consistent sequence of multiples of 15.625. But if I had the browser running, it looked like the more tabs I had opened, the more inconsistent the times where (but still leaning towards multiples of 15.625). And if a tab had something **loading**, the numbers started looking like a regular sequence of 1 to 1!

So, I concluded that whevener I had to do testing, I'd put a Youtube or Twitch tab by the side. It's weird as hell (if there's a better way to do it, I'd like to know), but for now, I will have to unite the useful with the pleasent, lol

Comment: You could also increase the priority of the process you use for timing.